# Gitlab 7.7 create new/move repository not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab, gitlab-7

I migrated from Gitlab 7.5 to 7.7 as well as setup entire new installation of Gitlab 7.7 but both items are showing the same issue.

Creating a new repository results in error "Failed to create repository", moving an existing repo to another namespace gives "Cannot move project".

In both cases I neither see an error in any of the gitlab logs nor any request to gitlab-shell.

Here is my system information:

production.log

```
Started GET "/test/gitlab-shell-mirror/edit" for 9.155.131.22 at 2015-01-26 14:31:00 +0100
Processing by ProjectsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"test/gitlab-shell-mirror"}
Completed 200 OK in 90ms (Views: 60.8ms | ActiveRecord: 7.1ms)
Started PUT "/test/gitlab-shell-mirror/transfer" for 9.155.131.22 at 2015-01-26 14:31:08 +0100
Processing by ProjectsController#transfer as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "project"=>{"namespace_id"=>"48"}, "commit"=>"Transfer", "id"=>"test/gitlab-shell-mirror"}
Started PUT "/test/gitlab-shell-mirror/transfer" for 9.155.131.22 at 2015-01-26 14:31:08 +0100
Processing by ProjectsController#transfer as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "project"=>{"namespace_id"=>"48"}, "id"=>"test/gitlab-shell-mirror"}
Completed 200 OK in 476ms (Views: 4.7ms | ActiveRecord: 12.2ms)
Started PUT "/test/gitlab-shell-mirror/transfer" for 9.155.131.22 at 2015-01-26 14:31:08 +0100
Processing by ProjectsController#transfer as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "project"=>{"namespace_id"=>"48"}, "id"=>"test/gitlab-shell-mirror"}
Completed 200 OK in 765ms (Views: 3.5ms | ActiveRecord: 411.5ms)
Started GET "/test/gitlab-shell-mirror/edit" for 9.155.131.22 at 2015-01-26 14:31:08 +0100
Processing by ProjectsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"test/gitlab-shell-mirror"}
Completed 200 OK in 262ms (Views: 240.9ms | ActiveRecord: 6.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 619ms (Views: 3.6ms | ActiveRecord: 119.0ms)
```

sidekiq.log

```
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.1
2015-01-26T12:53:03Z 48180 TID-4i8ak INFO: Booting Sidekiq 2.17.8 with redis options {:url=>"unix:/var/run/redis/redis.sock", :namespace=>"resque:gitlab"}
2015-01-26T12:53:03Z 48180 TID-4i8ak INFO: Running in ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
2015-01-26T12:53:03Z 48180 TID-4i8ak INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2015-01-26T13:12:31Z 48180 TID-o4kzc PostReceive JID- INFO: start
2015-01-26T13:12:31Z 48180 TID-o4kzc PostReceive JID- INFO: done: 0.642 sec
```

rake check:
    git@lh-aux-git:~/gitlab> ./bin/check
    WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.1
    Checking Environment ...

```
Git configured for git user? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 2.4.1 ? ... OK (2.4.1)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
Satellites access is drwxr-x---? ... yes
hooks directories in repos are links: ...
test / gitlab-shell-mirror ... ok
Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files:
        /var/git/repositories: OK
        /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
Test redis-cli executable: redis-cli 2.8.6
Send ping to redis server: PONG
gitlab-shell self-check successful

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP users with access to your GitLab server (only showing the first 100 results)
Server: ldapmain


Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
Database contains orphaned GroupMembers? ... no
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
projects have namespace: ...
test / gitlab-shell-mirror ... yes
Projects have satellites? ...
test / gitlab-shell-mirror ... yes
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Ruby version >= 2.0.0 ? ... yes (2.0.0)
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.8.4)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

gitlab-shell.log

```
# Logfile created on 2015-01-26 14:03:32 +0100 by logger.rb/44203
D, [2015-01-26T14:03:32.395082 #48638] DEBUG -- : Performing GET http://lh-aux-git//api/v3/internal/check
D, [2015-01-26T14:03:34.730336 #48643] DEBUG -- : Performing POST http://lh-aux-git//api/v3/internal/allowed
D, [2015-01-26T14:04:15.324875 #48692] DEBUG -- : Performing GET http://lh-aux-git//api/v3/internal/check
D, [2015-01-26T14:04:15.334451 #48692] DEBUG -- : Received response 200 => <{"api_version":"v3","gitlab_version":"7.7.1","gitlab_rev":"41ab9e1"}>.
D, [2015-01-26T14:05:09.948270 #48718] DEBUG -- : Performing POST http://lh-aux-git//api/v3/internal/allowed
D, [2015-01-26T14:05:09.985614 #48718] DEBUG -- : Received response 200 => <{"status":true,"message":""}>.
I, [2015-01-26T14:05:09.985748 #48718]  INFO -- : gitlab-shell: executing git command <git-upload-pack /var/git/repositories/test/gitlab-shell-mirror.git> for user with key key-5.
```

Other operations like push/pull/commit/merge requests are working fine!

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks
Christian

Answer (score 1):

Update to 7.8 solved the move/add functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked permissions within your containing projects? Sounds like a permissions issue to me, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Yes, I also checked permissions, but I assume it was a Gitlab bug (somehow). Upgrade on 7.8 later on reenabled this functionality.